# convert to an UIImage (iPhone) a data stream from an asp.net web service

Tags: asp.net, iphone, web-services, uiimage

I developed an asp.net web service that send an image and i want to convert the received data stream to an UIImage in my iPhone

this is a sample of what i get from the web service

> R0lGODlhbQCdAOYA...KsxbcSAAOw==

thank you in advance !

Comment: This looks like a Base64 string...

Answer (score 3):

This is an base64 encoded string, so you need to first decode it and then put it into an NSData object.
The next thing is to create an UIImage from the NSData object, this can be done like this:

```
NSData *myData;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:myData];
```

Answer (score 0):

And in order to encode/decode Base64 encoded strings into NSData, see the following [post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html). At the end there's a link to a NSData category that does Base64 encoding/decoding.

Comment: i used this NSData category and UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:myData]; and i get an exc_bad_access

Comment: Do you retain the myData variable before doing what you posted above? If you look at the code in the category, the NSData that is returned is autoreleased. Anyway, can you edit your post and put the whole code for your method (or the whole relevant part).

Comment: thank you ! that's it, i just replaced *image = [UIImage imageWithData:myData]; by *image = [[UIImage imageWithData:myData] copy]; and replaced retain the myData accessor by assign
i

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you replace retain with assign and used copy instead of retain? Copy creates a whole new object out of myData. Why isn't retain enough in this scenario?

Comment: BTW, if this was the answer you were looking for, please accept it. Thanks!